# How to copy MS teams recording to specific onedrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've created a sample Teams meeting application as mentioned in https://damienbod.com/2021/09/20/creating-microsoft-teams-meetings-in-asp-net-core-using-microsoft-graph/; this works fine. After the meeting, the link to the recordings is automatically posted to the meeting's channel. That is accessible only to the users who have O365 logins. Instead, can the recordings be copied to a specific onedrive account now created under the presenter account?

Comment: Could you please refer this doc(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/tmr-meeting-recording-change#set-up-the-meeting-recording-option-for-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint)?

Comment: Thank you Prasad, I've already setup the OneDrive to get the recordings. My requirement is how to download the recordings from OneDrive to another blob storage programmatically.